# Generic use of not yet existing enum in interface or abstract class

Tags: java, generics, enums

I'm about to create multiple search-DTO-Class to build and transfer search query parameters. Which parameters are available is dependent of the database table of an object.
Due to that, it is not possible to have only one `Enum` for every DTO-class, resulting in each DTO-class having their own `Enum` of searchable parameters.

The actual collection of search parameters will be an `EnumMap` (intizialized, but empty). I want to have a `getter`, `put` and `removeParameter` method in each search-DTO-Class.

Those three methods equal in logic in every DTO-Class but their return type differs (Map). So my question is:

**Is it possible to declare those three function generic?**
I have though about an interface which is to be implemented by any search-DTO-Class. But then I'd need to work with wildcards which does not meet the purpose of individual `Enum`s.

Example code:

```
public class LocationSearchParametersDTO

{
    public enum LOCATION_PARAMETER
    {
        ID("id");
        private String queryParam;

        private LOCATION_PARAMETER(String queryParam){ this.queryParam=queryParam; }

        public String getQueryParam(){ return queryParam; }
    }

    private final Map<LOCATION_PARAMETER, String> searchParameters = new EnumMap<>(LOCATION_PARAMETER.class);

    public Map<LOCATION_PARAMETER, String> getParameters(){ return Collections.unmodifiableMap(searchParameters); }

    public void put(LOCATION_PARAMETER param, String value){ searchParameters.put(param, value); }

    public void removeParameter(LOCATION_PARAMETER param){ searchParameters.remove(param); }

}
```

Comment: I have the feeling that you are reinventing the wheel.

Comment: Might be. Please detail your impression.

Comment: If the DTOs are a pure "copy" of your database tables, then you would probably save time by using tools that auto-generate them.

Comment: They are not exact copies. Search DTOs might include other search DTOs and the number of fields (db columns) is drastically reduced. I apprectiate your thoughts and feedback about this, but it is not really about the actual question.

Answer (score 0):

The tricky thing is that you need enums.

If you would have LOCATION_PARAMETER classes you could have them extend BaseParameter and then return something like

```
public Map<? extends BaseParameter, String> searchParameters(){}
```

Your idea of having the enums extend a common interface and have it as a return type would work, so I think you have to go with interface if you need to return enums.

EDIT:
Or you could have it unbounded and return your enums:

```
 public Map<?, String> searchParameters(){}
```